# SelectList retains selected state

Tags: react-native

I'm using npm package react-native-dropdown-select-list for a dropdown. The selection is working fine and setting the corresponding state variable: setSelected={ (key) => setBackend(key)}. The problem I'm having is that for some reason this state/selection is always retained. If the user navigates away from this page and comes back either via bottomtabnavigation, back button or organically via other means, the previous selection is always displayed.

I'm using a focused effect on this page to ensure that when a user returns all state is re-initialized to defaults e.g. setBackend('') and I confirm via console.log that it is indeed working for all "other" state variables in use. The relevant code is below:

```
const [backend, setBackend] = useState('');
const isFocused = useIsFocused();

init() {
  setBackend('');
  // reset all other state variables as well / these working
}

useEffect(() => {
  if(isFocused) {
    init();
  }
},[isFocused]);

return (
<SelectList setSelected={ (key) => setBackend(key)} data={backendList} placeholder="Select Backend"/>
)
```

However, as mentioned the previous selection continues to be shown as selected despite all state variables being reset ''! Does this api have an internal state where it retains this information, and if so how can I reset or disable that? If there's some other sorcery at work that's alluding me I would appreciate some insight. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this post and is facing a similar issue, the problem is not with `SelectList` dropdown API or state variables somehow retaining state despite being reset. The problem may be with navigation in my case. Bottom tab navigator was preventing the re-render of pages to improve performance. The solution that worked was to configure the bottom tab navigator screens with the following options:

```
unmountOnBlur={true} 
options={{unmountOnBlur: true}}
```

After this revisiting the page showed that nothing was yet selected. Interestingly, I no longer needed watch `isFocused` either since the stack was effectively being reset.

Before:

```
<Tab.Screen name={homeScreen} component={Home_Screen}/>
<Tab.Screen name={confScreen} component={Conf_Screen}/>
<Tab.Screen name={settingsScreen} component={Settings_Screen}/>
<Tab.Screen name={storageScreen} component={Storage_Screen}/>
```

After:

```
<Tab.Screen name={homeScreen} component={Home_Screen} unmountOnBlur={true} options={{unmountOnBlur: true}}/>
<Tab.Screen name={confScreen} component={Conf_Screen} unmountOnBlur={true} options={{unmountOnBlur: true}}/>
<Tab.Screen name={settingsScreen} component={Settings_Screen} unmountOnBlur={true} options={{unmountOnBlur: true}}/>
<Tab.Screen name={storageScreen} component={Storage_Screen} unmountOnBlur={true} options={{unmountOnBlur: true}}/>
```